# Communicate with BTLE device from backgrounded iOS app

Tags: ios, ios5, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How can one communicate with BTLE enabled devices in the background of iOS 5?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: So I can ensure I do not do this again, can you please explain to me how my question is unclear? The question is: Is it possible to use BTLE in the background of iOS 5.0, and there is a clear and accepted answer.

Comment: Questions that include the words "Is this possible" (for which a mere "yes" or "no" provides a satisfactory answer) generally have other "low quality" issues; this is evident in the answers your question attracted. I'll reopen the question, however.

Comment: Thank you, I will rephrase my question to better reflect the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same question (issue) last week and someone gave me the answer. It is possible, and to do so, you need to add the following setting to you info.plist file:

UIBackgroundModes (or Required background modes) -> "bluetooth-central"

Comment: Thank you very much man, I figured there had to be something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to your question per see, but I was thinking of doing the same and found out the following requirements ( which drove me away from using it):

This is part of ios 5.0 SDK

The support is only for Bluetooth 4.0 devices, ie iPhone 4S only right now and for devices that support that, ie. consequently can attach to bluetooth 4.0 standard.

Just fyi..
Some [Reference](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/92349-ios-5-bluetooth-updates.html) .

Comment: We are definitely aware of the current limitations of the spec at the moment, but we still want to proceed. However, I cannot figure out if Apple will allow BTLE in the background like they do with regular MFI certified, standard bluetooth devices. So far, all my testing points to no, which is not good. Has anyone else found anything different?