# How can I detect iphone notification signal in CoreBluetooth when App runs on Background mode?

Tags: notifications, core-bluetooth

I want to get CoreBluetooth notification signal when my app is on spacified activity and in background mode.

I want to detect this signal to wakeup the App to play the music. It's that possible.

Comment: This question is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717453/communicate-with-btle-device-from-backgrounded-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

In your Info.plist add a UIBackgroundModes property and include bluetooth-central in the array.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html